# Brass vs copper sponge for cleaning soldering iron?

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

[Brass sponges are liked by some](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371836/wet-sponge-or-brass-sponge-for-solder-tip-cleaning) for cleaning soldering iron tips

Many of the product on Amazon describe themselves as having a brass sponge, but some  reviews say that the sponge is in fact copper, not brass, and express this as a problem.

Is this a problem? Is there a reason to prefer a brass sponge over a copper sponge?

Comment: Brass is copper alloy.

Comment: It won't matter for this but brass will be cheaper and less a waste of copper.

Comment: Copper is better. Otherwise solder wick braids would be made out of brass, not copper.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the reviewers were complaining about it being copper for no reason. Good to know.